# How can I tell which event fires when I click on an HTML object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools, ie-developer-tools

I'm trying to download and re-use [the phone simulator here](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/overview/index.html), and I want to find the javascript that allows me to switch devices in the "OS Simulator mode".

Right now I have a local instance working, but the page isn't refreshing as it should be.  I tried the Javascript console in chrome but I don't see any events " fly by " as I click on the object and wait for something to happen in the F12 window.

How do I get the event name for the Javascript that should be firing?

Comment: I am confused, do you want to know how to find the event being triggered on the site you provided?

Answer (score 1):

## Add the below code snippet:-

```
function eventLogger(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

$(document).bind("click keydown keyup mousemove", eventLogger);
```

you can add/update the bind events to get log on additional events you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this:**

```
$("*").click(function(){

       alert($(this).prop("tagName"));

});
```